# How do I make the Nautilus sidebar default to tree view?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus

Yesterday, I just noticed how every time I click on my Home folder the sidebar view would go back to its Places view instead of the Tree view.

I tried using this command but it didn't work. Is there a way to solve this another way?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "tree"
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug to me. I can't reproduce it. Can you describe "click on my home folder" more precisly? You click on your home folder in the sidebar?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Instead of adding a "thank you" answer, please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 7):

**Using the application Menu:**

Go to the menu view → sidebar → tree

---

**Using a graphical interface:**

If you want to change it using a graphical application, you will need **dconf-editor**:

- install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools)
- start **dconf-editor**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> → dconf-editor
- navigate to org  → gnome  → nautilus  → window-state
- change the value of **side-pane-view** to “tree”.

*To install via command line:*

open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.

---

**Using the command line:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "tree"
```

Comment: @izx, for the purpose of completeness, I placed three options that I know of :) (not only for the OP, but future visitors as well)

Comment: @Zuul thank you. I did the last two solutions you provided, restarted my laptop and it worked.

Comment: All this unfortunately no longer works: "No such key 'side-pane-view'" (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @lmeurs Yap, appears to have been removed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505070/nautilus-unable-to-enable-tree-view-in-ubuntu-14-04