# Nautilus unable to enable tree view in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

Using **dconf-editor** I tried enabling

```
org -> gnome -> nautilus -> list-view -> use-tree-view
```

[image]

but even after the check box is selected, plus a reboot, it still doesn't switch to the tree view on the side bar.

In previous versions of Nautilus / Ubuntu the **side-pane-view** setting used to be in the **window-state** section (which is now missing)

[image]

I'm I missing something, or is there no way to enable Tree View on the side bar in 14.04?

Is there a way to manually create the missing entry back in **window-state** ?

Comment: just fyi, Dolphin can do this. make sure to right click on the folder side bar area and enable 'hidden', I thought it didnt 'follow' the main frame navigation, but it does.. (also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=865296)

Answer (score 4):

Simple as checking a box. And then you can use <- and -> arrow key to open and close folders.
[image]

Comment: This is not what was asked in the question. OP asked about the tree view in side bar

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is:

"Ubuntu 13.04" (onwards) "uses Nautilus 3.6 by default, for which some features that were available in Nautilus 3.4 are no longer available, such as the dual pane view, sidebar tree view and more."

Shocking discovery for me when I upgraded :-(

Comment: Why do people keep destroying open software?

Comment: @Rodrigo GNOME people became stubborn

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120109/222808