# How to customize Nautilus to display directory tree in the sidebar?

Tags: nautilus, files, directory

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS a little while and I consider myself a beginner.

I am using the Nautilus file manager:

[image: Nautilus screenshot]

I wonder if you can navigate the folders through the directory tree, like in Windows through folders or the + sign.

[image: Windows XP screenshot]

[image: Windows 7 screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the Nautilus sidebar default to tree view?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152071/how-do-i-make-the-nautilus-sidebar-default-to-tree-view)

Comment: @mikewhatever nope. No longer possible so that q got invalidated

Comment: Yes, here's the new link: http://askubuntu.com/q/505070/367990

Comment: just fyi, Dolphin can do this. make sure to right click on the folder side bar area and enable 'hidden', I thought it didnt 'follow' the main frame navigation, but it does.. (also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=865296)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Install Nemo file manager in Ubuntu (Unity)**

**Warning**: do not use this PPA if you're using Linux Mint or if you use Cinnamon in Ubuntu! Also, if you've added any Cinnamon PPAs, remove them before using the WebUpd8 Nemo PPA even if you didn't install Cinnamon, or else the Nemo version in the WebUpd8 Nemo PPA might be overwritten.

Update: the PPA now provides Nemo 2.8 for Ubuntu 15.10, 15.04 and 14.04.

Add the PPA and install the latest Nemo with Unity tweaks/fixes by using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

To launch Nemo, search for "Nemo" in Dash - no application called "Nemo" will show up but instead an application called files should be displayed - that's the app you need to launch. Don't search for "Files" because that will also find Nautilus (which is also called "Files").

Why use Nemo? Well, Nemo comes with a huge number of features that no longer exist in Nautilus (**including treeview sidebar option**). To see other tips like make Nemo your default file manager, etc. go to:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

Comment: Hello @xangua, installed and quite liked the Nemo, but it does not display the directory tree of my subfolders, is there any way of nemo display subfolders of my markers?

Comment: Bookmarks? Your have to change to tree view.

Comment: Yes @xangua, how to I do to be able to view the subfolders of my bookmarks in the directory tree?

Comment: Go to /home/youruser/ ?

Comment: For example /home/ricardoramos/Doutorado is a bookmark folder

Comment: Sounds like the regular nautilus is enought for you.

Comment: Hello @xangua, the view I needed was in the lower left corner, it all worked out! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Looks good, and it seems in Ubuntu 16.10, the answer has become as easy as `sudo apt-get install nemo`, without any need for a PPA.

Answer (score 7):

That feature got [deleted](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=ef467c8775392d0f0feb0e38f7a80f2d41719d84) from Nautilus by William Jon McCann. Reason:

> Use a list model instead of a tree model
>
> It is the list view after
>   all. Tree models don't work well on touch and it isn't consistent with
>   the file chooser.
>
> https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676531

Oh the changes made to Nautilus to remove it are in the link so feel free to fork Nautilus and re-install that alteration. Or pick another file manager (see the other answer)

Comment: There's already a fork :D

Comment: link!!! @xangua

Comment: Hello @Rinzwind, thank you so much for the information!

Answer (score 5):

I have Nautilus version 3.14.3

You can get something like "Tree view" with next steps:

1. **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Views** (tab) > **View new folder using** > [select] **List view**
2. **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Display** (tab) > [check] **Navigate folders in a tree**

See more detailed answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/519188/586427